# How to Change Text Format of Embed Text in Flash AS2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have one dynamic text field in the instance name `my_text`. I have set the Embed option in that file. because i need to rotate the text field. Now I need to change the font format of dynamic text field.

I have tried both the code is not working.

```
var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
myTextFormat.font = "Arial";
_root.text_dy.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
```

If i set the `embedFonts = false` and tried it is working. But I dont want to change he embed type. please How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

you have to embed the Arial font to get this to work - otherwise flash will look for an embedded version of the Arial and doesn't find one -> so the textfield stays empty.
if you set `embedFonts = false` flash just uses the locally installed version of the arial.

here is an very informative article about embedding fonts in flash:
http://www.codeandvisual.com/2010/how-to-embed-fonts-in-flash-for-use-with-dynamic-text-fields-and-complex-formatting/

Comment: hi. I will explain what i want exactly. I have one dropdown. it show different type of font name like "Arial", "Verdana". As per the user select i need to change the style of text in dynamic text field. If i not using the embed option of the text file the above code is working fine. But if i set by embed option of the text box that code is not working. I hope you understand, Please help me

Comment: yes, i understand you. but to use `embedFonts = true` on a textfield you actually have to embed the font into your swf. there are many ways to embed a font and the link i posted before explains some of them.